# Solidify modifier gap

Tags: modeling

I'm super new to blender and wanted to make some simple heart shaped object.

I've created this, but adding a solidify modifier makes a gap, which obviously I want to fill. I got no idea how to do this, due to my lack of experience.. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 Hi. We should be removing "thanks" and "any help appreciated" from posts, not adding them in. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @Kuksu i guess you have that kind of solidifying because the left and right half of the mesh are un-joined( you might have used a mirror modifier).

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 not in this case. These are my steps: 
1. built a heart shape from one cube and two cylinders as separate objects
2. joined them 
3. removed front, back and inner unwanted faces (leaving only heart shaped flat sides)
4. added thickness with solidify modifier (as suggested here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108512/intersection-of-beveled-curve-object )

Comment: So you r saying that you made it with 3 different objects. Can u post an image of the entire mesh in edit mode? I think you have a screwed up topology

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 edited

Comment: Ok...Now my question is where did you solidify it and why?

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 hopefully it's clearer right now. looks like I DID sth wrong with the top, like something is not connected properly, but I have no idea how to clean it up..

Answer (score 3):

Just as I said in the comments, it's happening because you you used two separate mesh (two cylinders) which's vertices were so close that you wont notice that there are **two** vertices. ***Solidify modifier does something similar to extruding and scaling inwards.***

Its just an easy process. I will walk you through it-

First of all apply the object's scale with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *scale* *(or else it will create uneven solidification)*.

Then go to `Edit Mode` and box select the vertices as shown and merge them with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> > `Merge at center`.  (Just  <kbd>M</kbd>  in Blender 2.83 and above)

[image]

**Notice how the gap gets filled...**

Comment: @kuksu does this answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

**Bevelled curve alternative**

This is not answering how to close the solidify gap, more offering an alternative to makng the object.

Add a default bezier circle and enter edit mode.  By default all points are selected.  Set the handle types (particularly of top and bottom) to free

***`Control Points > Set Handle Type > Free`***

[image]
*Minimal effort example*

Next add a plane, in edit mode delete its only face, exit edit mode and

***`Object > Convert > Mesh to Curve`***

it is now a "square curve" and can be made the bevel object of the heart.  Scale plane to desired size.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that even though you joined the three objects together, there are still two/three distinct meshes within the object with duplicated vertices in the center. You can check this by selecting a vertex then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (Select Linked).

[image]
[image]

You can fix the issue by selecting the adjacent vertices and *Merging* them by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> > *At Center*. Note that I'm using the select box in wireframe mode with X-Ray enabled, this is so that the selection will catch any vertices that are hidden behind other geometry.

[image]

If you don't like the uneven result, change the solidify modifier mode from *Simple* to *Complex*

[image]